# Git packed-refs aliases break shallow fetch

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket

Can someone please tell me what's the refspec format in 'packed-refs' in Git repository, like this:

```
<some-hash>  refs/tags/anytag
^<tags-commit-true-hash>
```

As a result, when I perform `git ls-remote`, I get

```
<some-hash>             refs/tags/anytag
<tags-commit-true-hash> refs/tags/anytag^{}
```

So, when I attempt to shallow fetch `anytag`, I receive FETCH_HEAD pointing to `<some-hash>`, but after checking it out I receive `<tags-commit-true-hash>`. This breaks shallow fetching same tag, as data is pulled anyway (even if it's already there).

Local Git version: 1.9.1 Linux x86-64 on Linux Mint 17.3

Git hosting: Bitbucket

Does anyone know how to either remove those strange hash aliases or workaround their presense?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks shallow fetching"? I don't see anything in your question that would indicate anything would not work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "aliases" are tag objects. They contain extra comment and point to the actual commit (similarly to how the commit points to the tree and the tree points to the subtrees and blobs).

As far as I can tell, they work as designed. There is no need for any "workaround".

> This breaks shallow fetching same tag, as data is pulled anyway (even if it's already there).

No, data that is already there is **not** pulled.

There is a bit of *extra* data that needs to be pulled, but it is really just a little bit. The commit itself and the trees and blobs referenced in it shouldn't be pulled if they are already available.

Comment: I see this not for all tags. Another repo has a big bunch of tags which don't have accompanying 'tag objects'.
As of 'little bit of data', I'm using repository in question to store large binary blobs. Please don't ask me why, I'm just doing this. So, for certain states I can get 20Mb fetches. For the same shallow state.

Comment: Okay, so I figured out the difference between lightweight tags and full tag objects. And this was the issue root cause. So I mark your response as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Target-san, but the large objects are stored in (below, through 2 or more more references) the commit. The tags themselves shouldn't be that big, and the fetch should understand it does already have the underlying commit (if it, actually, does).

Comment: I know that tag objects shouldn't be that big. I'm just telling you what I encountered. Yes, that's strange. But that's what I got. The only reason I can guess is the packing.